# CheckBrowseMode vs Post

Tags: delphi, dataset

I maintain some legacy code where intensive use of `TDataset.CheckBrowseMode` is made instead of `Post`.

Could you please tell me the advantages of this?

Comment: This link gives a desription similar to the Delphi help one: https://microolap.com/products/connectivity/postgresdac/help/TPSQLDataset/Methods/CheckBrowseMode.htm anyway still it is not clear why i shuold use a method "used internally by many dataset methods"

Comment: You don't have to, but you can use it if the method behaviour fit your needs. Why reinventing wheels. If it not fits, then build a new one or simply call `Post`. But you have to ensure that the current state allows `Post` (`CheckBrowseMode` does so) otherwise you will get an exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental difference between `.Post` and `.CheckBrowseMode` is the control of state/changes in a DataSet. 
If you try to post the data in a DataSet which is not in `dsEditModes` an `Exception` will be raised.

Answering your question the advantage is:

In cases when the State is not in `dsEditModes`, if you call `.Post` you will get an Exception.

Also, when no record is modified and one calls `.CheckBrowseMode`, TDataSet will call `.Cancel` and thus, it will trigger all it's respective events.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i noticed the answer months in late. Anyway  in my legacy code i always have `Mydataest.Edit; MydatasetField.asinteger := 23; Mydataset.CheckBrowseMode;`. so really i do not see the need for `CheckBrowseMode` since the dataset is forcefully set to editmode manually every time. So `Post` would do the same, but for some unknown reason the original developer decided to use `CheckBrowseMode`.